# What does '-p' do in node CLI?

Tags: node.js, typescript

For example:
npx tailwindcss init -p
or
tsc -p .

I've noticed that running "tsc -p" and "tsc" have the same effect. What does -p do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a typescript compiler flag not a node one. stands for project.
the command:
tsc -p 'some_path'
it asks the compiler look for tsconfig.json file in 'path' and the compile using the compiler options in tsconfig.json

Comment: And all the options can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: I think `-p` is alias for `--project`? But now I actually cant find it in the Typescript doc ...

Answer (score 1):

the answer to the title of the question is:

1. `node -p` stands for "[evaluate and --print](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#-p---print-script)" (like `-e` but with output)

however the provided example brings in some confusion:

2. `tsc -p` stands for location of [config --project](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)
3. `npx -p` stands for [--parseable or --package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx#compatibility-with-older-npx-versions)
4. `npx tailwindcss -p` would be a flag for [tailwindcss CLI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is different depending on context. In [npm/npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx#compatibility-with-older-npx-versions):

> The `-p` argument is a shorthand for `--parseable` in npm, but shorthand for `--package` in npx. This is maintained, but only for the `npx` executable.

In the [Node.js CLI](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/run-nodejs-scripts-from-the-command-line/#pass-string-as-argument-to-node-instead-of-file-path) (from [man page](https://manpages.org/nodejs#options)):

> `-e`, `--eval string`
> Evaluate string as JavaScript.
>
> `-p`, `--print string`
> Identical to `-e`, but prints the result.